# Eclipse console: revert line order

Tags: eclipse, console

I would like to change the order of the Eclipse default console output. 
I would like to always have the more recent log lines first.

Does exist a way to do that ? preferences / plug-in ?
I don't want to always scroll down after each unlock of the console...

Answer (score 1):

If you unlock the console, it will jump to the end when the next output is printed. Another option is to click on the huge text field and press <kbd>Ctrl+End</kbd>.

I don't know a plugin or preferences setting which would do "scroll to bottom on unlock".